# Inexpensive industrial/medical keypads

Tags: hardware, keyboard

Has anyone got experience with manufacturers of industrial/medical keyboards or keypads?

I'm trying to find a relatively inexpensive (as in not $200+ per unit) keypad (for bulk order) that would meet the following specifications:

- PS/2 or USB interface (USB prefered)
- Sealed design to prevent dust/moisture from getting between the keys. A membrane keypad in a solid housing (not one of those cheap rollup keyboards) would be a good possiblity
- Should be able to take rough use from non-technical users
- Easy cleaning is a plus

To save money however it does not:

- Does not need to stand up to intentional abuse (vandalism)
- Does not need to operate in extreme environments (only office level humidity/temperature)
- Does not need to be customizable. A standard numeric keypad is enough

Comment: What kind of environment are these keyboards going to be in? Do you have a real need for a rugged keyboard or do you just have bad luck with users abusing keyboards?

Comment: What is your price limit?

Answer (score 1):

Cherry has a broad range of [Industrial/Medical Keyboards](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/Industrial/index.htm). I have never used one of these Industrial ons but I have seen many in factories, they are quite popular at least in Germany.

To prevent dust/moisture there is a [flexible dust](http://www.cherrycorp.com/english/keyboards/Industrial/Keyboard_Cover/index.htm) you'll have to order as an extra.

Cherry has no pricing information on their website and you'll have to look for an retailer in your area. 200 USD for a rugged keyboard is a little unrealistic I guess, I think it is more about 400 USD.

You can try to buy a regular (quality) keyboard an combine it with a flexible dust cover from
cherry or another manufacturer.

Cherry is also the manufacturer of "Das Keyboard" by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You might actually not need to get ruggedized keyboards.  They are so cheap now, that it might make sense to just buy a box of 10 or so.  Toss them when they get dirty/stop working.

I frequently see super cheap keyboards on Newegg for about $4 to $5 including shipping.

Comment: The replacement cost of the keyboards is not the issue (I just don't want to submit a budget request for 200 keyboards at $250 each), it's the cost and time of sending out tech support to replace them. The keypads would be connected to locked down access stations (PC inside a steal box with a rugged touch screen - keypad is needed for PIN codes) installed at remote locations with no on site technical expertise. With only 1 or 2 units per site, downtime and costly onsite support due to "guy with oil covered hands gummed up the keyboard again" isn't acceptable.

Comment: Ah ha.  I withdraw the answer then ;-)